How can I figure if a query is CPU-bound or I/O-bound?
I have a query that runs regularly. It runs in under a second, but I consider it too slow and I would like to tune it. I can either monitor it as it runs live or copy the query text and run it myself. The query plan is a classic "Wide, per-index updates" plan. It is almost identical to the below, with the only difference being that I have inserts rather than deletes.

I am sure that my bottleneck is during the index-modifying steps. It is either due to CPU usage (the indexes are PAGE compressed) or the reads required to insert into the indexes (they are billions of rows). But I would like to know which it is!
I can easily find the total time the query runs for as well as the time spent on CPU (sp_WhoIsActive and SET STATISTICS TIME ON both present this readily), but how can I specifically find the time spent on logical reads during this query? Ideally, I would specifically like to know the time spent on logical reads during the index modification steps.
SQL Server 2022. Compatibility level 140.

What are the operator timings for each operator? (as shown in the actual execution plan)

@MartinSmith Why would that matter? I can read the timings on each operator, but I don't believe that answers the question. If I know that the clustered index insert takes 0.1 seconds, then how do I know how much of that was CPU time (e.g. PAGE compression's penalty) and how much was I/O time?

Logical reads are from memory.  This is likely wrapped up in the CPU time.  I don't know of a separate counter for reading instructions and doing memory ops by the CPU.  I don't believe you will find an easy way to isolate it.  If there is an easy one, I want it!
A WAG if you like to experiment.  Reduce the memory timing in the BIOS to measure the effect. If the CPU used remains the same and the query takes longer, the CPU does not include the logical IO.
I think it's a good question.  If a dozen SQL Servers are on the same host, there is only so much memory bandwidth.  Yes, it should not be an issue....
